# Retopology question: Which direction of the edges?

Tags: modeling, retopology

I’m stuck in this retopology (a sprayer bottle) and need some tips, inspiration or instructions.

(1) The question is what direction of the edges you would prefer.

(2) Is my approach wise at all?

To grasp the bottle shape my approach was first to model the base “hard surface-ish” then retopo upon it to achieve the beveled details and for easier texturing.

Yet whatever I try the transition from the bend “cover panel” to the bottle neck the geometry appear unpleasant and dented.

Any help is appreciated with gratitude:)

Kind regards,
Raaskot

Ps.: don’t mind the 2.79 UI. I use 3.0 on my other system;)

[image]

Comment: you should begin with a shape that is as simple as possible imho, also work with one object and one mesh only

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if that will answer but I would redo it from scratch and make it as simple as possible.

- Extrude a plane along the main face:

[image]

- Extrude the result:

[image]

- Extrude the neck along Z:

[image]

- Give it some corrections, make the top circular:

[image]

- Create these edges with the knife in order to follow the object shape:

[image]

- And so on:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot @moonboots for your generous feedback! This is utterly helpful and very didactical. 
     Yes, I need to scrap my first attempt and use your approach instead. Actually it reflects the same strategy I have observed from other sources and using the knifetool makes sense. I guess the task getting the neck sufficiently rounded may be a challence but I'll go on and try it out. 
Kind regards and thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, what do you mean with the neck sufficiently rounded? You can do something round with a low-poly mesh

Comment: I guess @Mikael might mean _Loop Tools > Circle_ ?

Comment: Robin Betts: Correct, Or like shift-alt-s. That was what I reflected upon. Since the "canopy" part on the neck is strictly geometrical -- yet with a soft beveled transition to the rounded neck compared to the photo -- I imagine modelling this part without projected support may be challenging and perhaps produce an uneven form with bevel artefacts. Or I may be wrong. In any case I will try out @moonboots suggestion:)